# appropriate method for text match in one column to other column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to write a query in Oracle. I have a table called 'Entity' with 2 columns 'Pref_mail_name' and 'spouse_name'.
Now i want list of all spouse_name where the last name of the spouse_name is not populated from pref_mail_name.
For example my table has following data

```
Pref_mail_name            spouse_name       

Kunio Tanaka           |  Lorraine            
Mrs. Betty H. Williams | Chester Williams    
Mr. John Baranger      | Mrs. Cathy Baranger  
William kane Gallio    | Karen F. Gallio     
Sangon Kim             | Jungja
```

i need output as 1st and 5th row only. I did some analysis and came up with oracle built in function

```
SELECT PREF_MAIL_NAME, SPOUSE_NAME, UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(a, b) 
similarity from entity
order by similarity;
```

But above query is not looking genuine.Even though spouse last name is not populated from pref_mail_name its giving a value above 80 for similarity.

Comment: what are `a` and `b` in your query? can you provide a reproducible test case? my instance shows < 50 for rows 1 and 5 and >= 64 for the rest

Comment: Will the last word always be the last name? If so why not just compare if the last words are the same - there's no need to use similarity funcitons

Comment: This will be close to impossible. You can look at the last word, but the last word might be a name suffix i.e. "Jr.", which means "Jennifer Smith" and "Bob Smith Jr." will not make a match. You can use the match like you are now, but "Christine Tell" might report a match with "Christine Hill". Not to mention that many wives no longer take their husbands last names.

Comment: Hello..my query was                                               SELECT PREF_MAIL_NAME, SPOUSE_NAME, UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(PREF_MAIL_NAME, SPOUSE_NAME) 
similarity from entity
order by similarity;                                                      Always last name is displayed in the last..can you please tell me how to break words in pref_last_name and spouse_name and compare their last names?Iam ok if some rows miss where there is JR,i can do them manually by some other approach